# Why is it reading [object Object]?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to read from Firebase, but I keep on getting this [object Object]. I don't know if I am reading wrong or if there is something wrong  with my database. I've also tried using jQuery, but it's not working. It might be something really simple that I'm missing.

```js
//var transcript_title = null;
//var transcript = null;
//This is to intialize everything and auth. with the firebase server
var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyB9p1VvVfhnbrcDwUKUuSqw9aQsqnDi4nQ",
    authDomain: "html5project-870df.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://html5project-870df.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "html5project-870df",
    storageBucket: "html5project-870df.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "54935462861"
};

//firebase.initializeApp(config);
//checks if it has been init
if (!firebase.apps.length) {
    firebase.initializeApp({});
}

//declare variables
var database = firebase.database();
//tells where the items are going to be 
var Rootref = database.ref().child("users");
var ref = firebase.database().ref("users");

ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
}, function (error) {
    console.log("Error: " + error.code);
});

//var Rootref1 = database.ref().child("users").child("id: 113295907411766134791")/*.child("trans")*/;
//used to retrieve data 
Rootref.on("child_added",snap => { 
    //gets the child of titles stores it as variable
    var transcript_title = snap.child("titles").val();
    //var transcript_title = (snap.val() && snap.val().titles);
    //gets the actual title and stores it as a var
    //var transcript = snap.child(transcript_title).val();

    $('#transcrip').val(snap.child('users/id: 107621796826103613669'))
    //jquery - way to add html elemnts with javascript

    $("#read").append('<h4 id = "clicked">'+transcript_title+'</h4>');
    //$("#read").append('<h4 >Test</h4>');

    //when button view was clicked it will show the transcriptiodn
});
```

```
{
  "users" : {
    "id: 107621796826103613669" : {
      "hi1" : [ "test" ],
      "hi2" : [ "hi" ],
      "hi23" : [ "hi3" ],
      "hi3" : [ "blaha" ],
      "test" : [ "blahblah" ],
      "test2" : [ "te2" ],
      "titles" : {
        "1" : "hi1",
        "2" : "hi1",
        "184" : "test2",
        "230" : "test",
        "1192012017" : "hi3",
        "2019201220" : "test"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You've not said which line of code is outputting that, but it means that you're trying to display a variable which holds an object where a string is expected, so the type is being coerced. To fix this you need to access the relevant properties of the object and display those, instead of the entire object itself.

Comment: "IT" is a clown.. and "it doesn't read. "It is processing" and it.. is likely to be a PC. Point is... the language interpreter reads something... and you are referring to an "read error" or another error type. State it as such in your question tag. It now did hit the "triage review" and its send to "requires editing" so you can fix and reformulate your question tag properly. Also include Rory's remark as such it reflect that you did something with that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reading the titles with:

```
var transcript_title = snap.child("titles").val();
```

Which translates to this JSON:

```
  "titles" : {
    "1" : "hi1",
    "2" : "hi1",
    "184" : "test2",
    "230" : "test",
    "1192012017" : "hi3",
    "2019201220" : "test"
  }
```

This is an object, so when you set it into the HTML, it will show that with `[object Object]` (note that different browsers may handle this differently). To get the full JSON as text in your HTML, you can us `JSON.stringify(...)`:

```
$("#read").append('<h4 id = "clicked">'+JSON.stringify(transcript_title)+'</h4>');
```

If you want to instead show all titles, you can loop over them:

```
snap.child("titles").forEach(function(titleSnap) {
  $("#read").append('<h4 id = "clicked">'+titleSnap.val()+'</h4>');
})
```